# mvc4 custom membership provider using nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4

I have implemented working solution of custom nhibernate membership provider to use in `mvc3` projects. It was separated web.membership project which covers all that I need in my web apps.

Now I want to switch to mvc4 and I have noticed that it uses `System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication` class in the `Account controller`, also it uses the `WebMatrix.WebData.Security` class.

If anyone know useful tutorials on how to write custom (nhibernate or not) `simple membership provider`  it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication` has absolutely nothing to do with Membership. This is used to emit forms authentication cookies and this was class was present since ASP.NET 1.0 and is not specific to MVC4.

The SimpleMembership Provider is indeed a new custom membership provider that was designed for ASP.NET MVC 4 and it uses SQL Server to query the database.

You could still use your custom membership provider in MVC4 without any problems. The Simple Membership Provider was created in order for users that do not have any existing membership provider code to get started with MVC. Since you already have a working implementation with NHibernate I would recommend you using that. The Simple Membership Provider was not intended to be customized that way.